# SRV records not created on new domain controller

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain, domain-controller

I've stood up a new domain controller and attached it to my existing domain and that seemed to complete without issue.  But then when standing up a new server and attempting to attach it to the domain using the new domain controller I got an error that it couldn't find the domain controller.  It turns out the new domain controller doesn't have ldap and kerberos SRV records for the new DC, only the old ones.  I've waited 48 hours and run ipconfig /registerdns and stopped and started the netlogon service as well as rebooted the computer.  Nothing seems to update those records for the new DC.

Comment: Hi, did you added the role and runned the dcpromo wizard without issue ?

Comment: First step: check DNS server addresses specified in IP config

Comment: Yes, dcpromo wizard ran without issue and all the networking is fine.  It seems like a completely setup domain controller but minus those records.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue

register in DNS setting

[image]